# get result where one column value is identical in two following rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select failed employees from `employeeExam` table where `status` column equals `0` for two following rows.

Result should be like this:

```
ID  COURSE_ID  EMPLOYEE_ID  DEGREE  DATE                             STATUS  NUMOFTAKINGEXAMS
4   2          4            17      January, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000   0       2
```

**Here is what I did:**
**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8567/6)**

To clarify more: when ordered by `id`, result should contains only exams' data which have the same `course_id` and `employee_id` and `status` = 0 under each other directly.

Comment: You mean you want to get the employees that have taken an exam at least twice and failed every attempt?

Comment: @ Marty McVry No, result should contains only employees who failed at least twice in adjacent way (when he failed this time and the next one) only. If he failed several times and succeeded in one while ordering by id not date, this will not be shown.

Comment: Could one take another exam of the same course when he/she has already passed?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out and comment:

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8567/37)

```
set @sum:=0;
set @id:=0;     

select distinct x.empid, x.degree, x.date, x.status
from (
select @sum:= (case when status=0
               and @id = employee_id then @sum+1
               else 1 end)
as sm,  @id:=employee_id as empid, degree, date, status
from employeeexam
order by employee_id)x
where x.sm >= 2
;

| EMPID | DEGREE |                           DATE | STATUS |
------------------------------------------------------------
|     2 |      5 | January, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      0 |
|     3 |      6 | January, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      0 |
|     4 |     15 | January, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      0 |
```

Comment: @Yasmeen is this what you are looking for? :) Please comment.

Comment: Not exactly. I want to show rows only where employee has at least 2 consecutive failed attempts. So in this case it should show row which has `EMPID` = 4 only.

Comment: If you look at your sample data, it seem these are the empid, degree with dates where they had at least two consecutive failures..

Comment: To clarify more:  when ordered by `id`, result should contains only exams' data which have the same `course_id` and `employee_id` and `status` = 0 under each other directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a portion of the SQL-code, to show the principle, although I doubt it fully extends your requirements. For example, this code doesn't check for consecutive failed attempts, only all attempts in general. It doesn't show any any rows of which the applicant has already passed an exam.

So for example: should one take an exam and get status 0, 0, 1, 0, 0; it would not show up, because applicant has passed at least one exam.

```
SELECT course_id, employee_id, MAX(degree), status, COUNT(id) NumExamsTaken
FROM employeeExam
GROUP BY course_id, employee_id
HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2 AND SUM(status) = 0;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8567/30/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT a.*
   FROM
      ( SELECT x.*
             , COUNT(*) rank
          FROM employeeExam x 
          JOIN employeeExam y 
            ON y.course_id = x.course_id 
           AND y.employee_id = x.employee_id 
           AND y.date <= x.date 
         GROUP 
           BY id 
      ) a
   JOIN
      ( SELECT x.*
             , COUNT(*) rank
          FROM employeeExam x 
          JOIN employeeExam y 
            ON y.course_id = x.course_id 
           AND y.employee_id = x.employee_id 
           AND y.date <= x.date
         GROUP 
           BY id 
      ) b
     ON b.course_id = a.course_id
    AND b.employee_id = a.employee_id
    AND b.status = a.status
    AND b.rank = a.rank - 1
  WHERE a.status = 0;
```